# Adding values to existing array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making an array that will look like this `var qwe = [[a,b],[c],[d]]` with the purpose of a and b being the identifiers.

a - d are coming from reading the DOM. My current JS is doing what I want it to but I want to combine the similar arrays by their identifiers. Running the below code will give me

```
qwe =[
[100,200],[3],[2],  
[200, 300],[12],[4],    
[100,200],[2],[6]
]
```

but I want the final array to add the similar arrays by their identifiers so it will end up looking like (based on previous example)

```
qwe =[
[100,200],[5],[8],
[200, 300],[12],[4]
]
```

### HTML

```
<table name="tab" id="tab">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="itinValue" value="100"></td>
    <td><input name="location" value="200"></td>
    <td><input name="num" value='3'></td>
    <td><input name="other" value='2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="itinValue" value="200"></td>
    <td><input name="location" value="300"></td>
    <td><input name="num" value='12'></td>
    <td><input name="other" value='4'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="itinValue" value="100"></td>
    <td><input name="location" value="200"></td>
    <td><input name="num" value='2'></td>
    <td><input name="other" value='6'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### JS

```
var table = document.querySelectorAll('[name="itinValue"]');
var qwe = [];

for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  var a = document.getElementsByName('itinValue')[i].value;
  var b = document.getElementsByName('location')[i].value;
  var c = document.getElementsByName('num')[i].value;
  var d = document.getElementsByName('other')[i].value;
  var x = [[a,b],[c],[d]];

  //Compare,find,add here

  //if identifiers do not exist
  qwe.push(x);

}
```

This is a fiddle to my example that also correctly outputs the html too https://jsfiddle.net/3oge7wxg/125/

Comment: Do you need to solve it *this* way?  I see what you are going with, but could we say, define X as something other than an array?  I was not sure if that is a design decision.

Comment: This was just my choice to do it this way, I know how to do it with just one identifier by doing an object instead of array but having 2 identifiers didnt work with objects.

Comment: well its just a hashmap and instead of overriding, you just add the sums.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try to find the item for updating and if not push the new array.

```js
var table = document.querySelectorAll('[name="itinValue"]'),
    qwe = [],
    a, b, c, d, i,
    item;

for (i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    a = +document.getElementsByName('itinValue')[i].value;
    b = +document.getElementsByName('location')[i].value;
    c = +document.getElementsByName('num')[i].value;
    d = +document.getElementsByName('other')[i].value;

    item = qwe.find(([[l, r]]) => l === a && r === b);
    if (item) {
        item[1][0] += c;
        item[2][0] += d;
    } else {
        qwe.push([[a, b], [c], [d]]);
    }
}

console.log(qwe);
```

```html
<table name="tab" id="tab">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="itinValue" value="100"></td>
    <td><input name="location" value="200"></td>
    <td><input name="num" value='3'></td>
    <td><input name="other" value='2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="itinValue" value="200"></td>
    <td><input name="location" value="300"></td>
    <td><input name="num" value='12'></td>
    <td><input name="other" value='4'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="itinValue" value="100"></td>
    <td><input name="location" value="200"></td>
    <td><input name="num" value='2'></td>
    <td><input name="other" value='6'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Version with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var table = document.querySelectorAll('[name="itinValue"]'),
    qwe = [],
    a, b, c, d, i,
    item
    map = new Map;

for (i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    a = +document.getElementsByName('itinValue')[i].value;
    b = +document.getElementsByName('location')[i].value;
    c = +document.getElementsByName('num')[i].value;
    d = +document.getElementsByName('other')[i].value;

    item = map.get([a, b].join('|'));
    if (item) {
        item[1][0] += c;
        item[2][0] += d;
    } else {
        item = [[a, b], [c], [d]]
        map.set([a, b].join('|'), item);
        qwe.push(item);
    }
}

console.log(qwe);
```

```html
<table name="tab" id="tab">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="itinValue" value="100"></td>
    <td><input name="location" value="200"></td>
    <td><input name="num" value='3'></td>
    <td><input name="other" value='2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="itinValue" value="200"></td>
    <td><input name="location" value="300"></td>
    <td><input name="num" value='12'></td>
    <td><input name="other" value='4'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="itinValue" value="100"></td>
    <td><input name="location" value="200"></td>
    <td><input name="num" value='2'></td>
    <td><input name="other" value='6'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am downvoting this by reasoning is that you are creating an n^2 problem out of something which should be and can easily be designed to run in n-time.

Comment: @Fallenreaper, you could use the version with a map. (but for the given data size, the performance does not matter, anyway.)

Comment: I dont see an upper bounds on set size to presume it a small set to justify that statement.  I see a code snippet of a size 3 table, where as this question can be applied to a LOT of different problems of varying length.  Even my questions end when my sample shows the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something called an associative array, "dict" in python, a key/value pairing, with the keys being your [a,b] part and the values your [c,d] parts.

You can emulate this in JavaScript through objects.

Further reading is here:

- [JavaScript Associative Arrays Demystified](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/)
- [JavaScript Basics: How to create a Dictionary with Key/Value pairs](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2015/09/05/JavaScript-Basics-How-to-create-a-Dictionary-with-KeyValue-pairs)

Answer (score 0):

I would use objects, just create a composite key:

```
var table = document.querySelectorAll('[name="itinValue"]');
var qwe = {};

for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  var a = document.getElementsByName('itinValue')[i].value;
  var b = document.getElementsByName('location')[i].value;
  var c = new Number(document.getElementsByName('num')[i].value);
  var d = new Number(document.getElementsByName('other')[i].value);

  var key = a + "_" + b;

  previousValue = qwe[key];
  qwe[key] = previousValue ? [previousValue[0] + c, previousValue[1] + d] : [c, d];

}
```

You can convert to your desired array like so:

```
Object.keys(qwe).map(key => [key.split("_")].concat(qwe[key]));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3oge7wxg/161/

Edit: Number constructors; Added fiddle

Comment: this is a great way to do it too

Comment: Objects are very flexible and useful in JS. I would suggest considering them every time you can create a key that identifies the data-set you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are key facts I am taking note of in your question:

- you are looping an array of data.
- you are storing data based on a key which is a tuple.
- values where key is a match is an addition option.
- a,b,c,d are all ints,so if these are strings, you would need to run parseint() if they are strings.  This can be done by checking if it is currently type is a string, and if so, convert it.

Since it is a tuple and those are not implmented in javascript, you can do something like this.

```
var m = {};
var table = document.querySelectorAll('[name="itinValue"]');
for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

  var a = +document.getElementsByName('itinValue')[i].value;
  var b = +document.getElementsByName('location')[i].value;
  var c = +document.getElementsByName('num')[i].value;
  var d = +document.getElementsByName('other')[i].value;

  var key = a.toString() + "-" + b.toString();
  //creates key = "100-200"
  if (m[key]){
    m[key] = [m[key][0] + c, m[key][1] + d]
  }else{
    m[key] = [c,d]
  }
}
```

in the end, your map will now have unique keys and a map that looks like:

```
{
  "100-200": [5,8],
  "200-300": [12,4]
}
```

and if for whatever reason, you need to break up they keys later, you just split on the key.   `map.keys[index].split("-")`

I think this is clean, but if you want to go a bit more, you could turn it into a class.

You then store the information in qwe.  If you need to, you can easily convert that from a map to a list, but it depends on your desired implementation goal. The key difference generally is whether or not you wish to maintain order.  qwe is populated only with this information, and given your comment based on this being your implementation not the best one, it gives me enough insight to believe that order isnt really as important as preservation of they key data elements, this key/tuple, and 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the amount of fields per row, here is an alternate way of retrieving your array.

```
var qwe = {};
var els = document.querySelectorAll('table#tab input');
for (i=0; i<els.length; i+=4) {
    var indexer = i < 4 ? 0 : i;
    var row = {
        a: [
            parseInt(els[indexer].value)
          , parseInt(els[indexer+1].value)
        ]
        , c: parseInt(els[indexer+2].value)
        , d: parseInt(els[indexer+3].value)
    };
    row.key = row.a.join('_');

    if (qwe[row.key]) {
        qwe[row.key][1][0]+=row.c;
        qwe[row.key][2][0]+=row.d;
    } else {
        qwe[row.key] = [row.a, [row.c], [row.d]];
    }
}

console.log( Object.values(qwe) );
```